# Python Selenium get value from certain class

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to get the information in `value=" "` from this code.
As long as the class has the word **orange** in it, I want to store the value.

Expected result in this case is storing value "JKK-LKK" in a variable.

```
<input type="text" readonly="" class="form-control nl-forms-wp-orange" value="JKK-LKK" style="cursor: pointer; border-left-style: none;>
```

I have tried using

```
text = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'nl-forms-wp-orange')]").get_attribute("value"))
```

But I get:

```
AttributeError: 'list' Object has no attribute 'get_attribute'.
```

I've also tried `getText("value")` but I get is not a valid Xpath expression.

If I try only using

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'nl-forms-wp-orange')]")
```

The list becomes empty.  So I feel like I might be missing some few other key pieces.
What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: Just remove the s from find_elements. You are using get_attribute on the whole list instead of a single element.

Comment: driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@class, 'nl-forms-wp-orange')]") should work for you. The text() function is used for innerHTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To print the value of the *value* attribute i.e. **JKK-LKK** from the elements containing *class* attribute as `nl-forms-wp-orange` you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.nl-forms-wp-orange").get_attribute("value"))
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@class, 'nl-forms-wp-orange')]").get_attribute("value"))
  ```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.nl-forms-wp-orange"))).get_attribute("value"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[contains(@class, 'nl-forms-wp-orange')]"))).get_attribute("value"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```